# Is there an easier way to construct an array of unique values from multiple collections of objects with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that contains two arrays of items. These items are structured the same and each have a "tech" attribute that is an array of strings. I want to print an array of all the possible unique strings that appear across all of the objects. The solution that I have included below works, but I'm wondering is there a more succinct way of accomplishing this task with lodash?

```
var data = {
    "sitesA" : [
        {
            "name": "Website Alpha",
            "tech": ["SASS", "Foundation", "jQuery"]
        },
        {
            "name":"Website Beta",
            "tech":["SASS","AngularJS"]
        },
        {
            "name":"Website Charlie",
            "tech":["CSS","WordPress"]
        }
    ],
    "sitesB" : [
        {
            "name":"OtherSite",
            "tech":["CSS","jQuery"]
        },
        {
            "name":"Bears",
            "tech":["SASS","AngularJS"]
        },
        {
            "name":"Taco Time",
            "tech":["CSS", "ASP", "SQL"]
        }
    ]
}

var tech = [];

_.each(data,function(collection){
    _.each(collection,function(item){
        _.each(item.tech, function(value){
            tech.push(value);
        });
    });
});

console.log( _.uniq(tech) );
// ^ returns desired result of: ["SASS", "Foundation", "jQuery", "AngularJS", "CSS", "WordPress", "ASP", "SQL"]
```

Comment: For reference: Have a look at using ES6 `new Set([])` to get unique values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = { "sitesA": [{ "name": "Website Alpha", "tech": ["SASS", "Foundation", "jQuery"] }, { "name": "Website Beta", "tech": ["SASS", "AngularJS"] }, { "name": "Website Charlie", "tech": ["CSS", "WordPress"] }], "sitesB": [{ "name": "OtherSite", "tech": ["CSS", "jQuery"] }, { "name": "Bears", "tech": ["SASS", "AngularJS"] }, { "name": "Taco Time", "tech": ["CSS", "ASP", "SQL"] }] },
tech = [];

   _.each(data , function(collection){
       tech.push(_.map(collection,'tech'));  
    });

console.log(_.uniq(_.flattenDeep(tech)));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var tech = _.uniq(_.reduce(data, function (memo, collection) {
    return memo.concat(_.flatten(_.map(collection, _.partial(_.get, _, 'tech'))));
}, []));
```

The explanation would be as follows:

1. Reduce the array into a new one that is created 'getting' the tech property of its inner components.
2. Due to the fact that 'tech' is an array, if you didn't apply `flatten`, you'd get a matrix (something that we don't want, so we 'flatten' the array)
3. Get rid of the duplicate items using `_.uniq`

Comment: I ended up going with the [answer suzo provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39840154/1608016) for sheer simplicity sake,  but I really like this answer and appreciate you taking the time to walk through it step by step :)

Comment: Thanks, @briceshatzer appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var data = { "sitesA": [{ "name": "Website Alpha", "tech": ["SASS", "Foundation", "jQuery"] }, { "name": "Website Beta", "tech": ["SASS", "AngularJS"] }, { "name": "Website Charlie", "tech": ["CSS", "WordPress"] }], "sitesB": [{ "name": "OtherSite", "tech": ["CSS", "jQuery"] }, { "name": "Bears", "tech": ["SASS", "AngularJS"] }, { "name": "Taco Time", "tech": ["CSS", "ASP", "SQL"] }] },
    techSet = new Set;

Object.keys(data).forEach(k =>
    data[k].forEach(o =>
        o.tech.forEach((new Set).add.bind(techSet))));

console.log([...techSet]);
```